# Styled components in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

How can i apply my css code as styled-component in app.js ?
How can i convert this ".container > div" into styled-component and use it in my app.js . After installing styled-component through npm install then importing it. I am stuck here . I am not able to apply some css style in styled-components.

**App.js**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import './App.css';

 class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return (

      <div class="container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      </div>
           );
         }
       }

 export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
.container
 {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
   grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
 }

.container > div 
 {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 2em;
   color: #ffeead;
 }

html, body 
 {
 background-color: #ffeead;
 margin: 10px;
 }

.container > div:nth-child(1n)
 {
  background-color: #96ceb4;    
 }

.container > div:nth-child(3n) 
 {
  background-color: #88d8b0;
 }

.container > div:nth-child(2n)
 {
   background-color: #ff6f69;
 }

.container > div:nth-child(4n)
 {
   background-color: #ffcc5c;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a component based on a `div` that serves as container and write down your CSS. The trick here is to apply the appropiate style to the children `div` of the component `Container`, you need to use `&` (represents the parent selector) inside the template literal to create the needed nestings so SC can generate the appropiate CSS classes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import './App.css';

const Container = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;

  & > div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ffeead;
  }

  & > div:nth-child(1n) {
    background-color: #96ceb4;    
  }

  & > div:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: #88d8b0;
  }

  & > div:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #ff6f69;
  }

  & > div:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: #ffcc5c;
  }
`;


class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Container>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```